# Java hibernate SQLQuery

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Делаю запрос в `БД`, но мне возвращается `Null`. При таком же запросе через `pgAdmin` результат есть. В чем может быть причина?

```
mySignals =session.createSQLQuery("SELECT result, time FROM signal sig INNER JOIN sensor_signal sen_sig ON (sig.sensor_signal_id = sen_sig.id) " +
                    " INNER JOIN sensor sen ON (sen_sig.sensor_id = sen.id)" +
                    " INNER JOIN measurement me ON (sen_sig.measurement_id = me.id)" +
                    "WHERE  sensor_id = ? AND me.time >= ? AND me.time <= ? AND dimension_id = ?").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MySignal.class))
                    .setInteger(0, sensor.getId())
                    .setDate(1, dateFrom).setDate(2, dateTo).setInteger(3,d.getId()).list();
```

В логах вывожу значение параметров:

```
dateFrom = 2015-09-28 16:25:00.856
dateTo = 2015-09-28 16:25:00.856
sensorID = 28
dimensionID = 19
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ошибки какие нибудь есть?

Comment: нет, ошибок никаких. После запроса еще в логи вывожу размер коллекцииmy Signals.size = 0

Comment: Поставьте в конфиг <property  name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property> и смотрите что генерирует хибер. Этот запрос выполните в pgAdmin и посмотрите что выдаст

Comment: Я так и сделал. В логах вывожу запрос hibernate и следом вывожу свои параметры. В pgAdmin у меня запрос выдает результат

Comment: Я не знаком конечно с java  но разве не надо  обрамлять одинарными кавычками дату ?

Comment: в логах постгресса параметр передается как $2 = '2015-09-28 00:00:00'

Comment: Попробуйте убрать из хибернейт запроса все параметры и выполните запрос, если всё гуд, возвращайте по одному условию и смотрите, что происходит, результаты запроса корректные или нет. Уверен что один(или несколько) из параметров передаётся некорректно(вероятнее всего что-то не так с датами)

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен! Надо было указать `.setTimestamp(1, dateFrom)`, вместо `.setDate(1, dateFrom)`, тогда время учитывается!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте значение параметра явно преобразовывать к типу даты, т.е.

```
cast(? as timestamp)
```

Comment: изменил на me.time >= CAST(? as TIMESTAMP) результат опять пустой